# Angular google maps scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

im working on a thing were im using angular google map. But i cant figure out how to initialize it in a proper way.

On init i run a function that draws some plots on the map. My concern is wheter i shouold use "uiGmapIsReady.promise()" or "uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then". When im using "uiGmapIsReady.promise" the map loads smoother but no plots gets drawn and. When im using 
"uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then" the plots get drawn, but the map inits 3 times and feels slow. So how is the proper way of doinf this?

Dont mind the double use of "init", its just for demonstration.

Code:

```
    $scope.map = { 
        center: { 
            latitude: 67.855800, 
            longitude: 20.225282 
        }, 
        zoom: 13,
        options: { 
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
        }
    };

    uiGmapIsReady.promise().then(function(maps) {
        $scope.init();     
    });



    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        $scope.init(); 
    });


    $scope.init = function() {

        $scope.plots();     
    };

    $scope.plots = function() {
        MapService.plots().then(function(result) {
            //using a directive to draw plots.
        });
    };
```

Here is the service:

```
export default function MapService() {
return ['$http', function($http) {

    this.plots = function() {
        return $http({
            url: '../json/plots.json',
            method: 'GET'
        });
    };
}];
}
```

Comment: What is `MapService` ? Custom service? If yes show it's implementation. If not, what library is it a part of?

Comment: its a custom service wich just returns some json for lat/long. That service works, so its not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Added it to my question tho.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

- `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` *provider* is used to determine whether Google Maps API is loaded
- `uiGmapIsReady` *service* is used to determine whether map instance(s) is rendered on the page

Basically, if there is no any dependency to Google Maps API in your json data (e.g. `google.maps.LanLng` object) then there is no need to wait until Googlr Maps API loaded or map is rendered. Otherwise i would prefer to utilize `uiGmapGoogleMapApi`for data loading and binding.

**Example**

```js
angular.module('map-example', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])

  .factory('MapService', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    var MapService = {
      plots: function () {
        return $http.get('https://rawgit.com/vgrem/d4b3e3c21149ebce3cd523036b02a72e/raw/data.json').then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      }
    }
    return MapService;
  })

  .controller('MapController', function ($scope, uiGmapIsReady,uiGmapGoogleMapApi, MapService) {

     $scope.markersData = [];

    $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: -25.350480,
        longitude: 134.474842
      },
      zoom: 4,
      options: {
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
      }
    };
    

    //uiGmapIsReady.promise().then(function (maps) {
      //$scope.init();
    //});



    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
      $scope.init();
    });


    $scope.init = function () {
      $scope.plots();
    };

    $scope.plots = function () {
      MapService.plots().then(function (result) {
        //console.log(result);
        $scope.markersData = result;
      });
    };

  });
```

```css
.angular-google-map-container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.1/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.11/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="map-example" ng-controller="MapController">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" control="map.control">
      <ui-gmap-markers models="markersData" coords="'self'" idkey="'id'"></ui-gmap-markers>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
  </div>
```

**Update**

[This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ynRksUY1POXUw9PWF59j?p=preview) demonstrates how to initialize polygons (`ui-gmap-polygon` directive) from external json data

Comment: Thank you sir! In this case im using ui-gmap-polygon. Does that make any difference? Cause my polygons are not visible anymore. I get the json response tho.